# Mail not sending

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-email

In my SharePoint 2013 environment, I have a approval workflow that configure to send mail at each level of approval, to concern person.  The issue is, some time mail triggered successfully and some time not within a single thread of process(with the work flow status: **The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly**)

Even I tried it while keeping the same mail account all level of approval it just send mail randomly a any level of the approval but not at all level of approval.

I thought, there might be something wrong with my workflow, so I configure the alert (at all events) on some list and libraries too. But here also some time mail triggered and some not.

any body have any suggestion on it !!!

Comment: Does the farm have multiple SharePoint servers? Have you configured the mail server to accept e-mail from all servers in the farm? If you have two SharePoint WFE servers, and only one of them is configured on the mail server to be allowed to send mail, then if a user is being served from the SharePoint server that the mail server is not configured for, that would generate the message you are seeing.

Comment: I have two WFE server in the farm, Mail setting is configured at both server at SharePoint level as well as IIS level.

Comment: can we send mail via outlook configured in the SharePoint server itself !!

Comment: No, you need to configure SharePoint to send e-mail via a mail server (Exchange for instance). In the outgoing mail settings, you'd normally specify the SMTP server name, or address, a from address and a reply-to address if the from address is not a monitored mailbox. The SMTP server needs to be configured to accept unauthenticated mail connections from both of your SharePoint servers.

Comment: Andy..  All these setting are configured like wise....,  my concern is this ,that some time mail shoots and some time not !!!

Comment: Can you try an experiment? On both servers, try telnetting to the mail server, i.e. 'telnet mail.domain.com 25' and see what you get in return. Doing this you are emulating what SharePoint would be doing. If you receive a reply from the mail server (0ther than connection closed), then you can try issuing mail commands against the mail server, e.g. EHLO server.example.com . If from either server you see a 'connection refused' or something similar, then it's most likely the mail server configuration (e.g. receive connector on Exchange) that's not configured to allow that WFE to send mail.

Comment: This tests the basic communication from the SharePoint servers to the mail server to ensure that the underlying connection is functioning.

Comment: I found that it was due to the Sending IP address was in block-list on public domain, as it is dynamic IP, now I'll assign a static one.   I ll check once it will be static...  any ways thanks for your suggestion Andy..  :)